# how to read data from one table with two forignkey in laravel

Tags: laravel

i'm biginner in laravel, and have three table,tasks table have two forignkey to Offices and Statuses tables:

```
tasks
-------
office_id (FK)
status_id (FK)
 
offices
---------
id
caption

statuses
-------
id
Desc
```

in Task.php Model:

```
public function Office(): BelongsTo 
{
 return $this->belongsTo(Office::class); 
}
public function Status(): BelongsTo 
{
 return $this->belongsTo(Status::class); 
}
```

in Office.php Model:

```
public function tasks(): HasMany    
{       
 return $this->hasMany(Task::class,'Office_id');                       
}
```

in Status.php Model:

```
public function tasks(): HasMany    
{       
 return $this->hasMany(Task::class,'Status_id');                       
}
```

in index.blade.php :

```
 @foreach($tasks as $item)
<tr>
   <td>{{$item->id}}</td>
   <td>{{$item->Caption}}</td>
   <td>{{$item->Status_id}}</td> 
   <td>{{$item->Status->Desc}}</td>
   <td>{{$item->Office->caption}}</td>
</tr>    
@endforeach
```

when run, in index file `$item->Status->Desc` return null value and `$item->Office->caption` return caption value,
with dd method in index.blade.php :

```
#relations: array:2 [▼
   "Office" => App\Models\Office {#1328 ▶}
   "Status" => null
]
```

how to resolve it for null value?

Comment: Check the casing on your FK definition. Your database shows `office_id` but your relationship shows `Office_id`. casing is important.

Comment: It seems that the problem is not the office value because it returns the correct values. The problem is in the status value